# SSD Wiped Overnight

Tags: 15.10, ssd

I came home from work today to find that my laptop fans were running at 100% and my laptop was ridiculously hot to the touch. It had been fully powered off 14 hours prior and was not like this 9 hours earlier. It would not responded to my pressing the power button or any keyboard key; The laptop screen was black and not even powered on. I finally got the laptop to turn off and the computer would boot to a bios message "Operation System Missing". After removing the hard drive I discovered it is blank with no partition table. All the space is showing as unallocated in gparted. Does anyone have any insight into what could have happened? SMART test comes back 100% OK. It was running 15.10 updated less that 24 hours prior.

Comment: How many people have physical access to your machine?

Comment: So did you turn your machine off and then find that when you returned it was on again? Or did you leave it on while you were out?

Comment: @Rinzwind 0 people

Comment: @ParanoidPanda It was turned completely off

Comment: I'm going with Rinzwind here. It seems to me like somebody took your machine while you were away.

Comment: @bmandesign: Well, a machine can't be remotely turned on... So if you came back, it was on, and had wiped it self, that would mean that somebody came, turned it on, and then wiped it... Someone definitely would have had to have had physical access to the machine to do this.

Comment: @bmandesign it has to be at least 1 ;-) I am afraid the only 2 things I can come up with: someone in your house nuked your disk or you ran into some really weird bug. And I doubt *software* can do this. You can not get a running system to an "unnallocated" state if the disk is in use.It could be a hardware failure (but you might then be the 1st ever to experience it  ... this is really something I would have heard before since I myself did an extensive search on SDD failures before I decided to get me 1 ;-)  )

Comment: @TheBrownOne That is impossible. The laptop was at my house with a family member home the entire time; They don't have the technological knowledge to know what an ssd is, let alone delete the partition table.

Comment: I have reformatted the drive and filled it with randomly generated files, pulling the files off and checking sha256sum comes back 100% correct.

Comment: @bmandesign: Well we definitely know that somebody did something physical with it and was physically there. Because it **cannot** turn itself on, full stop.

Comment: @bmandesign Your family member could have Google'd up how to prank you just to be mean. It's happened before.

Comment: @TheBrownOne: Yes, or perhaps the family member just decided to have a joke or something, googled some stuff and then when things went wrong... Well, something bad happened...

Comment: @TheBrownOne It was filled with important data that they knew was there, and was just as important to them. The room was also locked and I had the key. They didn't have my password.

Comment: @TheBrownOne This would also be extremely weird behaviour for my mother that relies on the technology I run in the house.

Comment: @bmandesign So is your system is working fine now, except of course the obvious?

Comment: @JayT. The drive is perfectly functional and reads and writes with 0 errors so far. Other than the data that was lost and was unable to be recovered (except for the memtest in grub) despite trying every method I knew or could find on the internet. I am however very uneasy about using the laptop, despite what comments above say the device was not accessible to anyone else and left in the exact same place in the exact orientation. I even phoned everyone who had access to my house and asked if they touched anything that uses my network and they all said no. I don't want to lose data again.

Comment: I just flashed the iso I use for HTPCs and the laptop booted correctly.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Why couldn't Wake-on-LAN be used to power on the device?